# Trying to query aws s3 object Using AWS query with select

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

Below is the piece of code i have written , to get the result but null in response
I am using selectObjectContent api to get the results with the simple SQL query

```
const bucket = 'myBucketname'
const key = 'file.json.gz'
const query = "SELECT * FROM s3object "


const params = {

    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
    ExpressionType: "SQL",
    Expression: query,
    InputSerialization: {
        CompressionType: "GZIP",
        JSON: {
            Type: "LINES"
        },
    },
    OutputSerialization: {
        JSON: {
            RecordDelimiter: ","
        }
    }
}



s3.selectObjectContent(params,(err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(data)

    } else {
            console.log(err)
    }
})
```

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a sample of the contents of your file. Also, if you use S3 Select in the Amazon S3 management console, does it work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to it. was logging error when getting successfull result/data , so corrected it below. Also i have found the way to read stream buffer data

```
s3.selectObjectContent(params,(err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)

    } else {
            console.log(data)
    }
})



const eventStream = data.Payload;
    // Read events as they are available
    eventStream.on('data', (event) => {
        if (event.Records) {
            // event.Records.Payload is a buffer containing
            // a single record, partial records, or multiple records
            var  records = event.Records.Payload.toString();
            
            console.log( records )


        } else if (event.Stats) {
            console.log(`Processed ${event.Stats.Details.BytesProcessed} bytes`);
        } else if (event.End) {
            console.log('SelectObjectContent completed');
        }
```

Comment: Consider using the V3 version of the SDK.